# Android requesting superuser command gingerbread 2.3

Tags: android

So I am making an app that request superuser permission and then on a button click will reboot the phone. This command below works fine in **[a modified version of]** android 2.2 api level 8 but when trying to use **[a modified version of]** gingerbread 2.3 api level 9 or 10 it will not open superuser pop up and will not reboot phone any reason why? Here is the code I have been using with 2.2

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
  switch (v.getId()) {
  case R.id.reboot_button:
      try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/bin/su","-c","reboot now"});
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Not all versions of 'su' hacked to permit escalation by ordinary users accept arguments.  You may also need to quote the the arguments to it.  It may be simpler to pipe the commands into the su process's stdin  It may also be that your modified 2.3 install doesn't have this superuser mechanism at all.

Answer (score 1):

The specific hack that was used to gain superuser access in 2.2 level 8 and below (*rageagainstthecage* was I believe the commonly used name) was closed in Gingerbread (this bit me too).

EDIT: @Chris Stratton pointed out something, and I totally forgot to mention it. Firmware upgrades typically wipe out the hooks put in place by most of the superuser exploits such as *rageagainstthecage*). You generally have to re-run the original tool that granted you `su` permissions after each firmware upgrade.

If you never had to run a tool to gain `su` access then I expect your new firmware build is simply missing the `su` binary and you may have to copy it into place by hand.

Comment: That's probably not directly relevant, as exploits are not usually used on-demand, but instead run once to leave behind some tools.  In this case likely an entire unofficial firmware?

Comment: You're actually right: forgot that firmware upgrades wipe out the hooks. *rageagainstthecage* was broadly speaking the exploit of choice for gaining superuser access in Eclair/Froyo, and it required that it be re-run every time a firmware update occured: each firmware update wiped out the hooks put in place by the exploit so you had to re-run it once after each firmware update (and THEN the tools are left behind). This worked fine until the hole it used (a buffer error in `adb` I believe) was closed in 2.3: running it now does nothing.

Comment: There are likely methods for most shipping versions of gingerbread.

Comment: You're right: there is I think a new one drifting around. The key thing is that if `su` wasn't baked into his original firmware build (and evidently isn't baked into the new one) then he will probably have to use one of the exploit tools every time he does a firmware upgrade.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help and quick answers.

Comment: Note that there is an 'su' binary in an official android install, it's just not one usable by unprivileged users - it only works "downhill".  So simply checking for its existence is not enough.

Comment: Thanks I was on a rooted 2.2 froyo rom and it worked and flashed cyanogenmod7 last night which is 2.3.4 tried running my app and it would not boot on button click

Comment: Isn't this a lot of trouble to maintain to avoid long pressing the power button and choosing reboot?

Comment: could there be something wrong with my code? I tried out this app called quick boot(reboot) and it rebooted the phone while running 2.3.4 gingerbread but it wont when trying with my code?